# Consequence of Nakayama Lemma's to Local Rings

Tags: ring-theory

I have read that Nakayama's Lemma has a nice consequence for local rings. If $R$ is a local ring with a finitely generated module $M$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then we see $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is a vector space over the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$. If a set $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ is a basis of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$, then pulling the $b_i$ back to $M$ gives a set of generators of $M$.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Consider the submodule of $M$ generated by the pulled-back elements and.. use Nakayama's lemma!

Comment: Read Theorem 2.3 in Matsumura's *Commutative ring theory*.

Answer (score 3):

(Mariano's comment suffices but let me write the idea as an answer for the sake of completeness. This post is community wiki so I will not gain reputation for upvotes (or lose reputation for downvotes!).)

If $b_1,\dots,b_n\in M$ and if $\overline{b_1},\dots,\overline{b_n}$ is an $R/m$-basis for $M/mM$, then let $N=b_1A+\cdots+b_nA$ (be the submodule of $M$ generated by $b_1,\dots,b_n$).

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $N+mM=M$.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that $N=M$ by remembering that $R$ is a local ring and applying Nakayama's lemma.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I did manage to prove $N+mM=M$, and now following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama's_lemma) I can quotient out $N$, to get $M/N = (N + mM)/N = mM/(N \cap mM)$. I would say $N$ is disjoint to $mM$ (i.e. their intersection in $(0)$), but then I only get $M/N = mM$. What's wrong?